# Loading an external application inside a PyQt/Qt application Window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Is it possible to ***load an application***  **inside a PyQt application window** or frame. For example loading **MOZILLA FIREFOX inside a Qt GUI Window**. What are the possibilities to achieve this.
Please tell me.

Comment: do you mean start a program or make the program shown in your app's GUI?

Comment: yeah... i want to run the application inside my app's gui.. is it possible?

Comment: I dont know ... or just impossible?